# jQuery filter using CSS class/subclass

Tags: jquery, css

Suppose I have this code:

```
<div class="notes">
    <div class="note">
         <div class="inner-content like"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="note">
         <div class="inner-content unlike"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="note">
         <div class="inner-content unlike"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want is to `filter` the like and unlike subclass.

I tried this code but no luck:

```
$("div.notes").filter(".note.note-inner>.like").hide();
```

The div that has like subclass is not hiding.

**UPDATE**

---

I want to hide the element with `.note` class not the one with the `.inner-note like`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek yeah you're right, I read it wrong.

Comment: Kindly check my update. These `note` are dynamically created using loop from a model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you don't have a `.note-inner` and your selectors are wrong. `.note.note-inner` would be an element with `class="note note-inner"`. And `.notes` is only 1 element, so `$.filter()` isn't going to find any other elements or the children in `.notes`

I think you meant  `$("div.notes").find(".note > .like").hide();` but you could also just do `$('div.notes > .note > .like').hide()` with or without the direct descendent selectors - they aren't necessary for the markup you shared.

If you want to remove a `.note` if it has a `.like` as a child, use `$("div.notes").find(".like").closest('.note').hide();`. That will find a `.like` inside of `.notes`, then find the closest ancestor with class `.note` and hide it.

```js
$("div.notes").find(".like").closest('.note').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notes">
  <div class="note">
         <div class="inner-content unlike">unlike</div>
    </div>
    <div class="note">
         <div class="inner-content like">like</div>
    </div>
    <div class="note">
         <div class="inner-content unlike">unlike</div>
    </div>
    <div class="note">
         <div class="inner-content unlike">unlike</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but I noticed that it left space between the filtered contents. Can I remove it instead of hide?

Comment: @ChristianMark what do you mean space between the filtered contents? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmxREE

Comment: supposed I have a fixed size for each note and I need filter the one with like class, the element is now hidden but left a fixed space relative to the size I set.

Comment: @ChristianMark show me a demo. If you `$.hide()` an element, it sets `display: none` which will remove it from the layout of the page. If you want to preserve the space, you want to change `opacity` or `visibility` instead of `display` to hide/show.

Comment: I got it based on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) applies to the elements you are going to filter, as such you want to apply it to the `<div class="inner-content .."></div>` elements:

```
$("div.notes > .note > .inner-content").filter(".like").hide();
```

Or simply

```
$("div.notes > .note > .inner-content.like").hide();
```

For removing the `.note` element you can just get the parent:

```
$("div.notes > .note > .inner-content.like").parent(".note").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 $(".note > .inner-content.like").hide();

 $(".note > .inner-content.like").show();
```

and

```
 $(".note > .inner-content.unlike").hide();

 $(".note > .inner-content.unlike").show();
```

I created a JSfiddle showing the filters with button toggles https://jsfiddle.net/jmbm2myu/3/